# Dockerfile: why is there no port exposing or RUN command? (angular-on-nginx dockerfile)

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

I'm setting up a docker container that will serve my Angular 5 application on a nginx server, following [this article](https://medium.com/@tiangolo/angular-in-docker-with-nginx-supporting-environments-built-with-multi-stage-docker-builds-bb9f1724e984).

The article proposes this Dockerfile:

```
# Stage 0, based on Node.js (for npm) to build and compile the Angular application.
FROM node:8.11.2 as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY ./ /app/

ARG env=prod
# For Angular 6: ARG conf=production
RUN npm run build -- --prod --environment $env
# For Angular 6: RUN npm run build --configuration $conf

# Stage 1, based on Nginx, to have only the compiled app, ready for production with Nginx
FROM nginx:1.15
COPY --from=node /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

I was wondering: why are the following not included?

- a port exposing instruction (e.g. `EXPOSE 80`), and
- a nginx run command (e.g. `RUN /usr/bin/nginx`)

The article doesn't talk about starting the nginx server in any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a port exposing instruction (e.g. EXPOSE 80)

The [`EXPOSE`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) instruction is more documentation than anything else. The [documentation for the nginx image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/) tells you to publish the port when you run the container with `-p 80:80`, which doesn't require an `EXPOSE` instruction. `EXPOSE 80` would allow you to use `-P` for the same purpose.

> a nginx run command (e.g. RUN /usr/bin/nginx)

The [nginx image](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/f603bb3632ea6df0bc9da2179c18eb322c286298/stable/stretch/Dockerfile#L99) does this for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Since your are using `nginx:1.15`, check its [*Dockerfile*](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/f603bb3632ea6df0bc9da2179c18eb322c286298/mainline/stretch/Dockerfile):

```
...

EXPOSE 80

STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```